# OnQuickLaunch is ignored

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list template with the OnQuickLaunch attribute set to true.  The default view for the list is set to a dummy page where some custom code runs, then sets the default view for the list to the "real" default, and then deletes itself.

When I create the list (through the UI) the OnQuickLaunch property is ignored.  What can I do to get SharePoint to honor the setting?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the attribute in the listtemplate is in uppercase (TRUE), some attributes in those provisioning files aren't case sensitive.